# How to add Slick in Magento 2?

Tags: slider, magento2.2.6, js-css

I have added slick.min.js in my custom module in the path below

> app/code/company_name/vendor_name/mymodule/view/frontend/web/js/slick.min/js

and my slick initialization js for my template is

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'slick'
], function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slider").slick({
        autoplay: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,

    });
});
});
```

and added in requirejs-config.js as

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'slick': "xxx_yyy/js/slick.min"
    },
    map: {
       '*': {
           slickSlider: 'xxx_yyy/js/slick-slider'
       }
   },
   shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
   },
};
```

Now it is working except the design. How to add slick.less and slick-theme.less files in custom module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a '**_module.less**' file and then call your less files in it.

Add your '**slick.less**' and '**slick-theme.less**' file under the following directory

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/source
```

Now create '**_module.less**' file as given below

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/source/_module.less

```
@import 'slick.less';
@import 'slick-theme.less';
```

Then run the deploy command

```
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Its may be help to you ...........

> https://blog.padoosoft.com/magento-2-with-slick-carousel/

Comment: stolen Inchoo article
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-slick-carousel/